# Pywin32 Excel Formatting

Tags: python, excel, pywin32

I want to write to an Excel sheet via pywin32. I can do it actually without problem. But I couldnt format a range of cells in sheet. I want to align the values centerly inside cells. And also i need to fill the cells with color. How can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've not specifically done this using python before, but I'm assuming you're using the COM automation interface to excel.

[This page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302084) has an example that seems to cover both alignment and filling cells with colour in C#, so it should be fairly easy to adapt to python.  Assuming you have a Worksheet object called sheet, and the Excel automation object is called Excel, I'm guessing it might look a bit like this:

```
//Format A1:D1 as center alignment, 
sheet.Range("A1", "D1").VerticalAlignment = Excel.XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter
sheet.Range("A1", "D1").HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter
sheet.Range("A1", "D1").Interior.ColorIndex = Excel.XlColorIndex.Red
```

If you don't have access to the Excel.XlAlign and XlColorIndex constants from python then you can just replace them with the specific integers they represent, though I'm not entirey sure where you could get them from.  Probably from a [VBA Reference Site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa221100%28v=office.11%29.aspx) or similar.  (Though that link I provided doesn't seem to allow you to expand each of the entries in the list, so you may need to look elsewhere)

EDIT: Just had a play about with excel automation via the python console, and it seems to work alright:

```
>>> from win32com.client import Dispatch
>>> xlApp = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
>>> xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add()
>>> xlSht = xlWb.WorkSheets(1)
>>> xlSht.Range("A1", "D1").VerticalAlignment = 1
>>> xlSht.Range("A1", "D1").Interior.ColorIndex = 6
>>> # The background color of A1-D1 should now be yellow
>>> xlSht.Cells(1, 1).VerticalAlignment = 1
```

If you can't find any good reference on what the various alignment/colour constants are, then I'd just play about with python on the console like this, then open the resulting worksheet in excel and have a look at the results to figure things out.

You can find the official reference for the office 2003 automation API [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa272268%28v=office.11%29.aspx)
Specifically, you'll probably find the [range documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174290%28v=office.11%29.aspx) most usefull.

Comment: The constants were veeerry irritating to track down for me. [This page](http://oreilly.com/catalog/pythonwin32/chapter/ch12.html) has the info on where they are located, under the header **Using COM Constants**.

Comment: Any chance you could elaborate on that?  I can't really help you make it work if I don't know what is going wrong...

Comment: Well. In your first suggestion, attributes are not recognized by python. In second suggestion,  the statement "xlSht.Range("A1", "D1").VerticalAlignment = 1 " didnt give any error but didnt align the range centerly.

Comment: Have you tried setting the VerticalAlignment or HorizontalAlignment to numbers other than 1 to see what effect it has?  I can't find a decent reference on what exact value each of the constants has, and can't get the constants themselves to work in python but seems likely that the correct values are fairly small numbers that you could find by playing about.  Sorry I don't have a better answer, but I don't have the time to play about much myself.

Comment: ok. thnx. I solved the alignment problem by using "sheet.Range("A37", "O38").HorizontalAlignment = 3". But this time, color can not be changed. ColorIndex is not recognized by python

Comment: Ah, my apologies, I read the ColorIndex bit wrong.  It's actually Interior.ColorIndex.  I'll update my answer to reflect this

Comment: Tt's ok. How can you find about these attributes? Because i want to adjust the borders also. And maybe other properties. Could you supply me your resources, please?

Comment: Google has been my main resource, but the official reference for the API is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa272268%28v=office.11%29.aspx (for office 2003 at least).

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is 12 years old, but for the benefit of anyone looking for the answer (like me), Microsoft now lists these constants here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.constants

(xlCenter, for instance, is -4108)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35407819)